# If a file or directory exist then overwrite

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting. If a file or directory (folder) exists then the script should overwrite it; if it doesn't exist then it should create a new file or directory.

This is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset File
unset Directory
echo -n "File:"
read File
echo -n "Directory:"
read Directory

if [ -f "$File" ]; then
    echo "file $File exist. Do you want overwrite it? (y/n)" 
    read yn                                              
    if [ $yn = "N" -o $yn = "n"];
    then
        exit 0
    fi
    echo "$File" >> testfile
else
    echo "file Does not exist"      
    touch $File
fi

if [ -d "$Directory" ]; then
    echo "directory $directory exist.Do you want overwrite it? (y/n)"
    read yn
    if [ $yn = "N" -o $yn = "n" ];
    then
        exit 0
    else
        echo "directory Does not exist"     
        mkdir -p  $Directory
    fi
fi
```

What changes do I need to make to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Yes often you do this. So what is your question and what have you tried so far? Please add your code to your question as well. And please see for [help] on how to behave on Stackoverflow.

Comment: For file, you can just do this: "> file path ". This overwrites if it exists, creates if not.  For directory, you need to define what overwrite means, if there are files in it. Do you just want to remove all the files?

Comment: You need to edit the question to define the desired behaviour.  And you need to learn how to debug a shell script (`bash -x script` or `sh -x script` or equivalent for whatever shell you use).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "$File" >> testfile
```

The above line 'appends' to a file named 'testfile'. It does not overwrite the file in question, which is $File.

```
if [ -d "$Directory" ]; then

    if [ $yn = "N" -o $yn = "n" ];
    then
        exit 0
    else

    fi
fi
```

In this part, you need to add an 'else' clause to outer if, not the inner one to handle the case of directory not existing.
Moreover '[ -d "$Directory" ]' test returns false if there is a normal file with the name '$Directory'. In that case, an attempt to create a directory with the same name fails.